# auto filtro Vba

Tags: vba

Estou desenvolvendo uma macro para realizar filtros utilizando o VBA, entretanto em algumas colunas, tenho que desmarcar alguns valores, por exemplo:

- Coluna
- Paulo
- Fernanda
- Carla
- Láis
- Renata

Eu quero tudo que seja diferente de Paulo, Fernanda e Renata. Como posso fazer isso?

Criei um macro que funciona com dois valores, caso eu coloco um só ocorre um erro, segue abaixo o código:

```
c = 1
      Do While c <= coluna
        If MyRange = Cells(1, c) Then
            filtrocomp = InputBox("Qual o operador de comparação?" & vbCrLf & "Ex: <,<=,=,>,>=,<>", "Comparação_MAF")
            filtro = InputBox("Qual o filtro de " & MyRange & " Deseja aplicar?", "Comparação_MAF")
            If filtrocomp <> "" Or filtro <> "" Then
                filtrosArray() = Split(filtro, ",")
                Val (filtrosArray(0))
                Cells(1, c).Select
                Selection.AutoFilter Field:=c, Criteria1:=filtrocomp & filtrosArray(0), Operator:=xlAnd, _
                Criteria2:=filtrocomp & filtrosArray(1)
                Exit Do
            Else
                MsgBox "Nenhum filtro foi realizado!!", vbInformation, "Comparação_MAF"
            End If
        End If
        c = c + 1
      Loop
```

Comment: Você sempre acessa filtrosArray(0) e filtrosArray(1). Se houver mais filtros ("Paula,Fernanda,Ricardo"), somente dois serão utilizados. Se houver um só, filtrosArray(1) causará um erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifiquei o código, deve funcionar para um filtro.

Também removi o `Val (filtrosArray(0))`, não fazia nada no seu código.

```
    c = 1
          Do While c <= coluna
            If MyRange = Cells(1, c) Then
                filtrocomp = InputBox("Qual o operador de comparação?" & vbCrLf & "Ex: <,<=,=,>,>=,<>", "Comparação_MAF")
                filtro = InputBox("Qual o filtro de " & MyRange & " Deseja aplicar?", "Comparação_MAF")
                If filtrocomp <> "" Or filtro <> "" Then
                    filtrosArray() = Split(filtro, ",")

                    Cells(1, c).Select
                    if ubound(filtrosArray)=1 then
                      Selection.AutoFilter Field:=c, Criteria1:=filtrocomp & filtrosArray(0), Operator:=xlAnd, _
                    Criteria2:=filtrocomp & filtrosArray(1)
                    else
                      Selection.AutoFilter Field:=c, Criteria1:=filtrocomp & filtrosArray(0)
                    End if                    


                  Exit Do
                Else
                    MsgBox "Nenhum filtro foi realizado!!", vbInformation, "Comparação_MAF"
                End If
            End If
            c = c + 1
          Loop
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi, além dessa correção, você quer usar mais critérios, certo?

Comment: RSinohara eu utilizo mais criterios sim, tem alguma outra forma que posso fazer? Além de dois critérios?

Comment: Teria um forma diferente de fazer isso?

Comment: Então, quis confirmar com você. O fato é que não tem como usando filtros como está fazendo, pelo menos não que eu saiba. O que pode ser feito é criar uma formula em uma coluna auxiliar (pelo VBA), e depois filtrar por esta coluna... algo como range("C" & linha).formula=filtro. A variável filtro aqui você carregaria com algo como "SE(B" & linha & ">10 AND A" & linha & ">7";1;0). E você filtraria essa coluna. Se servir explico/dou mais exemplos.

Comment: Então eu gravei uma macro no excel e apliquei um filtro e fui desflegando os itens e ela me apresentou os seguinte código!                                                                                    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AV$115846").AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:=Array _
        ("CODON_CHANGE_PLUS_CODON_DELETION", "EXON", "FRAME_SHIFT", "INTRAGENIC", _
        "NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING", "SPLICE_SITE_ACCEPTOR", "SPLICE_SITE_DONOR", _
        "START_GAINED", "STOP_GAINED"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Comment: Eu não consigo criar um vetor e a partir desses itens gravados aplicar um filtro?

Comment: Eu não sabia usar assim. Você pode criar esse array no código sim!

Comment: Por exemplo eu criaria um vetor e armazenaria as informações nele e com isso apenas iria armazenar os itens conforme acima!

Comment: Sim, você usaria a inputbox como no seu código, mas precisa testar para ver se aceita operador (o seu filtrocomp) ou se essa forma de filtrar só aceita filtrar itens. Mas uma pergunta: se o usuário pode escolher os filtros, porque não deixar que use a interface do Excel? É melhor que ter que digitar os valores (e possivelmente errar).

Comment: Por ser uma planilha com mais de 100 Mil linhas os mesmo tem algumas dificuldades para analisar os dados, são pessoas que não estão habituadas com o excel, mostrei  ele uma parte da forma que está e adoraram, é apenas um protótipo que estou fazendo.

Comment: Certo. Veja só. Deixar as pessoas digitarem o filtro é bem complicado (erro e trabalho extra). Você poderia exibir um formulário que percorre a planilha e apresenta as opções. Mas vai ser lento. E, no fundo, você está replicando a funcionalidade do filtro... analise se vale a pena.

Comment: Ok, vou verificar com o pessoal, ótima ideia é mesmo será bem mais lento, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25372/discussion-between-rsinohara-and-paulo-henrique-gallo).

Answer (score 0):

se voce tiver grupos de filtros pode criar uma tabela de *matching* e e uma coluna extra para fazer filtro. agora depende da complexidade.
exemplo coluna estado, coluna_aux
Inicio,Filtro tipo 1
secção 1, Filtro tipo 2
secção 2, Filtro tipo 2
secção 3, Filtro tipo 2
secção 4, Filtro tipo 2
Conclusão, Filtro tipo 1
Fim, Filtro tipo 1

por outro lado também pudemos fazer filtros com  wildcards do tipo "START_*", que devolve todos os que começam com "START_", ou então "*_SLB_*" todos os que tenham a palavra "*SLB*" seja no inicio, meio ou fim.

é uma abordagem diferente mas pode até ajudar o utilizador